# How to get a snapshot of a dynamic variable?

Tags: java, variables, methods

So I have a variable called "direction" which describes the direction my player is facing, duh. The problem is that I take in this variable when the player collides with something and if the player changes directions while inside an object weird things happen. For example, the player passes through a door (its a platformer) but if it switches directions the door gets flipped horizontally.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Assuming that you're using Eclipse, the duplicate will help you debug when the variable changes

Comment: I see you have marked it as a duplicate. Could you please link me to the original question?

Comment: Refresh the page and you'll see the link to the duplicate at the top.